# Adobe Illustrator - Export image with layer effect (multiply) to PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, export, illustrator-effects

Is it possible to save an image with layered effects (overlay) in PNG and maintain the same appearance that is seen in Illustrator?

[image: ZOOM PLEASE!]

I've tried different ways to export. Is there any other way to get the same colors seen in AI? (Without PDF).

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

If the part of the stone that you exported is sticking out against a transparent background, it may be just assuming the blend-moded shape's background is white. To have the stone be uniform color, you have to put in a shape of the desired background color behind the stone's shape so that the blending mode blends properly. So if you have a picture and export different layers and seeing unexpected results with blended shapes, you may want to create encompassing united shapes consisting of your current layer group art.

Comment: Hi Silly, sorry for the late response! When put an object behind the stone's shape, blending mode NOT blends properly. I exported the objects on single layer and I also tested exporting in different layers, and yet the result is indeed. What would be: "you may want to create encompassing united shapes consisting of your current layer group art."?  I am not a designer and I know the basics of AI, could you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Is your desired effect - the stone has only one color? Then you need to make the shape behind the darker half of the stone be edited to also be the background of the whole stone. You can copy/paste the stone shape in front of the background shape and use Pathfinder > Add (or they call it "unite" sometimes), to add the stone shape to your background shape. Now your original stone shape shall be multiplied against a consistent background and will be a single color.

Comment: Right! My stone has one color only. I' don't tested this, but anyway if I put something behind the image, it will not be more transparent, right?